# Running MaxEnt modelling in "dismo" using "loop" and storing the results in seperate objects and folders

Tags: loop, maxent, for-loop, habitat-modeling, dismo

I am doing a MaxEnt modelling using "dismo". I am using a loop to give multiple runs. I wanted to save results from individual runs in separate objects and at the same time the results from individual runs in separate directories.

The loop I have created runs without error. But when I am trying potential options to save the results, I am getting errors. The loop is as follows -

```
run = 2
for(i in 1:run){
group.k1 <- kfold(loxA.4, 5)
loxTrain.L1 = loxData.L1[group.k1 != 1,]
loxTest.L1 = loxData.L1[group.k1 == 1,] 
background = randomPoints(predictor0, 10000)
pseudo_absence_values = extract(predictor0, background)
pseudo_absence_values <- as.data.frame(pseudo_absence_values)
pseudo_absence_values$africa_ecoregion <- as.factor(pseudo_absence_values$africa_ecoregion)  
train_y = c(rep(1,nrow(loxTrain.L1)), rep(0,nrow(pseudo_absence_values)))
train_sdm_data = cbind(pa = train_y, rbind(loxTrain.L1, pseudo_absence_values))
Model.MT1 = maxent(train_sdm_data[,-1], p = train_y, path = "maxent/set_2/output"
show(Model.MT1)
Loop.r = predict(predictor0,Model.MT1, progress='text')
}
```

Comment: Please always include the error that you get from running any presented code.  Those errors should be presented as formatted text and not pictures.

Comment: Sorry about that. I realised that after posting it. However, I was able to work on it over the day I am posting it in the answer section. Hope that would come handy for all too.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to SE Cross Validated

Answer (score 1):

I worked on the problem through the day and came up with the following solution. I hope it will come handy for everyone.

```
# Creating the objects    
x <- stack()
    threshold.m <- vector("numeric", 2)
    auc.m1 <- vector("numeric", 2)
    l.T1 <- list()
    l.model <- list()

run = 2
for(i in 1:run){

  # Creating the k-fold data
   group.k1 <- kfold(loxA.4, 5)

   loxTrain.L1 = loxData.L1[group.k1 != 1,]
   loxTest.L1 = loxData.L1[group.k1 == 1,]


   # Creating the background points
   background = randomPoints(predictor0, 10000)
   pseudo_absence_values = extract(predictor0, background)
   pseudo_absence_values <- as.data.frame(pseudo_absence_values)
   pseudo_absence_values$africa_ecoregion <- as.factor(pseudo_absence_values$africa_ecoregion)


   # Creating the Analysis Data
   train_y = c(rep(1,nrow(loxTrain.L1)), rep(0,nrow(pseudo_absence_values))) # Main Training Data
   train_sdm_data = cbind(pa = train_y, rbind(loxTrain.L1, pseudo_absence_values)) # Main SDM Data

   Model.MT1 = maxent(train_sdm_data[,-1], p = train_y, args = c("-J", "-P"),path = "maxent/set_2/output")
   show(Model.MT1)
   l.model <- list(l.model, Model.MT1)


   # Doing Model Evaluation
   mod.evT1 <- evaluate(Model.MT1, p = loxTest.L1, a = pseudo_absence_values)
   l.T1 <- list(l.T1, mod.evT1)

   # Capturing the threshold values
   mod.thr <- threshold(mod.evT1, "spec_sens")
   threshold.m [i] <- mod.thr

   # Capturing the AUC values
   auc.T1 <- mod.evT1@auc
   auc.m1[i] <- auc.T1

   Loop.r <- predict(predictor0,Model.MT1, progress='text')
   x <- stack(x, Loop.r)
   }
```

The objects then can be used to analyse the relevant statistics.

There is only one problem that remains to be solved. How to save the results in a folder and how to display the Jackknife response curve.

Comment: To save the results folders separately use `file.rename("MaxEnt results", paste0("MaxEnt results ", i))`